# Doctrine2 - error when using @ParamConverter

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to retrieve object by translated slug, like so:

1 - I've made a custom repository with the method:

```
public function findByTranslatedSlug($slug, $locale)
 {
   var_dump($_locale);exit;
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
       ->where('c.slug = :slug')
       ->setParameters($slug);
   $query = $qb->getQuery();

   $query->setHint(
      \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
      'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
      \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE, $locale
   );
   return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

2 - my Action is configured with @ParamConverter like this:

```
/**
* @Route("/{slug}", name="name")
* @Template()
* @ParamConverter(
*     "content",
*     class = "StenikContentBundle:Content",
*     options = {
*           "mapping" = {"_locale": "locale"},
*           "repository_method" = "findByTranslatedSlug"
*     }
*  )
*/
public function indexAction($content)
{
   var_dump($content->getSlug());exit;
}
```

3 - Main routing

```
stenik_content:
    resource: "@StenikContentBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{_locale}
```

After trying to retrieve an object via `xxx.localhost/app_dev.php/en/some-slug` I'm getting a doctrine error:

> Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request
>   information.

I can't find what's causing the error, perhaps the repository method and mapping can't both be used together.  Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to check the behaviour directly, but I suspect the problem is that you have specified precisely which route placeholders match method parameters in your `mapping` entry, but not provided all the required parameters (and are also using a custom repository method).  Symfony would usually be able to guess how to use the placeholders to look up the entity, but not in abnormal circumstances.

EDIT: Just confirmed this in [Symfony source](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php) - if `mapping` is set then the Entity is retrieved by passing all the mapping info (in an associative array) into the `$repository->findOneBy` method, or the method named in `repository_method`.  This means that the method you choose will also need to expect an associative array as its parameter, not two separate `locale` and `slug` parameters.

So maybe try this?:

```
/**
* @Route("/{slug}", name="name")
* @Template()
* @ParamConverter(
*     "content",
*     class = "StenikContentBundle:Content",
*     options = {
*           "mapping" = {"_locale": "locale", "slug": "slug"}, #include slug here
*           "repository_method" = "findByTranslatedSlug"
*     }
*  )
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, but mapping only works with entity fields and i want to pass a locale for TranslatableListener. Any ideas?